# Where do the ladder operators come from in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, angular-momentum, lie-algebra

From what I've seen. Quantization of angular momentum arises from the allowable eigenvalues of the $J^2$ and $J_3$ when acted upon by ladder operators. We must set the allowable eigenvalues of these operators to the more recognizable quantized values of angular momentum. After the derivation you're supposed to be all like "oh that's why angular momentum is quantized". But the ladder operators just seem like a circular argument to me. Angular momentum is quantized because of how we defined the ladder operators. But where do these operators come from? How do they naturally arise when dealing with angular momentum?

To clarify why this is not a duplicate of [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/712815/): I'm asking how we arrived at the definition of ladder operators, not why they're important. Even if the ladder operators are axiomatic (which I don't think they are), what is the logic that made physicists think "hey lets define a very specific operator to change the angular momentum eigenvalue in units of h-bar"? How did we think the define it as $L_1\pm \mathrm iL_2$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importance of raising/lowering/ladder operators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/712815/)

Comment: @ZeroTheHero No

Comment: @Dutonic try this instead: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65784/. there are multiple variations of your question on the site.  Search for ladder operators.

Comment: The mathematical background for this is the [Cartan-Weyl basis](https://webhome.weizmann.ac.il/home/fnkirson/Alg13/10.Cartan-Weyl_basis.pdf) for Lie algebras, which involves finding “eigenoperators”

Comment: @ZeroTheHero yes, thanks for linking that

Answer (score 1):

> Angular momentum is quantized because of how we defined the ladder
> operators. But where do these operators come from?
> How do they naturally arise when dealing with angular momentum?

The ladder operators for angular momentum are not arbitrary.
They are derived by a quite long chain of conclusions
from the commutation relations of angular momentum.
$$\begin{align}
[L_x,L_y]=i\hbar L_z \\
[L_y,L_z]=i\hbar L_x \\
[L_z,L_x]=i\hbar L_y
\end{align} \tag{1}$$
For angular momentum $\mathbf{L}$ these relations (1) can be
derived from the definition $\mathbf{L}=\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{p}$
and the canonic commutators $[r_i,p_j]=i\hbar\delta_{ij}$.
But for spin angular momentum $\mathbf{S}$ these relations cannot
be derived from anything. So for spin we need to postulate (1)
as an axiom.
And then we can show that the total angular momentum
$\mathbf{J}=\mathbf{L}+\mathbf{S}$ also satisfies the relations (1).

From (1) we can prove $[L^2,L_z]=0$.
Therefore we know there are simultaneous eigenstates of $L^2$ and $L_z$.
We can call these states $|l,m\rangle$ where $l$ labels
the $L^2$-eigenvalue and $m$ labels the $L_z$-eigenvalue.

Now we *define* two operators $L_+$ and $L_-$.
$$L_\pm=L_x\pm iL_y \tag{2}$$

> what is the logic that made physicists think "hey lets define a
> very specific operator to change the angular momentum eigenvalue
> in units of $\hbar$"? How did we think the define it as $L_1±iL_2$?

These definitions (2) seem like arbitrarily grabbed from thin air.
But they are carefully chosen based on the commutator relations (1).
We actually need to *prove* that these two operators are
ladder operators. This proof (without the details) is sketched below.

It is not hard to calculate the commutators between operators (2)
and $L^2$ and $L_z$. Using (1) we find:
$$[L^2,L_\pm]=0 \tag{3}$$
$$[L_z,L_\pm]=\pm\hbar L_\pm \tag{4}$$

Now we can look for some properties of the states
$L_+|l,m\rangle$ and $L_-|l,m\rangle$.
From (3) we can prove:

- If $|l,m\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $L^2$,
  then $L_\pm|l,m\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $L^2$ to the same
  eigenvalue.

And from (4) we can prove:

- If $|l,m\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $L_z$ to eigenvalue $m\hbar$,
  then $L_\pm|l,m\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $L_z$ to the
  eigenvalue $(m\pm 1)\hbar$.

It is these last two properties which show that $L_+$ and $L_-$
are ladder operators. $L_+$ steps up the $L_z$ eigenvalue,
and $L_-$ steps down the $L_z$ eigenvalue by $\hbar$.
$$L_\pm|l,m\rangle \propto |l,m\pm 1\rangle \tag{5}$$